# How to correlate data from two separate tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I am a beginner at SQL. I am trying to write the following statement, but where user is in group (so where `group_members`.`user_id` = $_SESSION['user_id']).

```
SELECT `group_name`, `group_description` FROM `groups`
```

How do I write this sort of query that relates values from two different tables? Sorry if I haven't explained this well.

EDIT: When I use the query provided by Matthew Haugen, I seem to have the following difficulty: only one set of results is returned in an array.

This is my code for the function that does the query:

```
function group_summary(){
$sql = secure_mysqli("SELECT `group_name`,`group_description` FROM `groups` WHERE `group_id` IN (SELECT `group_id` FROM `group_members` WHERE `user_id` = ?)", array($_SESSION['user_id']), "i");
$groups = $sql;
return $groups;
}
```

And this is secure_mysqli:

```
function secure_mysqli($query, $values, $datatypes) {
    global $link;
    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $query);
    if($stmt !== false){
    if(is_array($values)){ foreach ($values as &$value) $ref_values[] = &$value;
    call_user_func_array("mysqli_stmt_bind_param", array_merge(array($stmt, $datatypes), $ref_values));
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    return @mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt));
}}}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I see you've been a member for a few months and you're just starting to ask questions, that's great to see. I've answered your question below, I think, but for future reference you might want to review some documentation on [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) questions in our format. For instance, we'd love to see some more details on what you've already tried, what has worked, and what hasn't.

Comment: @MatthewHaugen - cheers and well written.  Welcome 3430472

Comment: @MatthewHaugen I will read some of that documentation when I'm not coding :p.  I think it is something wrong with my code but only one set of values is coming out of mysqli_fetch_assoc with that query even when I create two groups

Comment: @petrus I'm not sure what you're looking for. I thought you wanted only one set of results?

Comment: @MatthewHaugen sorry if I wasn't very clear about what 'set of results' meant.  If I have two groups and I run the query and print an array from the results, I get  Array ( [group_name] => Group1 [group_description] => Group1 ) but no results for Group2

Comment: You're sure you *should* be getting results from Group2? The userid you're testing is in Group2? Sorry if that seems like a stupid question, but trust me, I've seen cases like that.

Comment: @MatthewHaugen No, it's a perfectly valid question, but yes, the userid I'm testing is in Group2

Comment: @Petrus wanna try the other query I gave you? Admittedly I've never once used MySQL before, so perhaps there's some behavior that's different from the T-SQL that I wrote those expecting. Furthermore, do you have any way of getting results directly? For instance, using SQL Server I'd have access to SSMS. Is there an equivalent? Then we can be sure that the issue isn't in your code anywhere, and is in fact the actual statement.

Comment: @MatthewHaugen Trying it now...

Comment: @MatthewHaugen In the end I used the first query, but a different way of extracting the results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you want either this

```
SELECT * FROM Groups
WHERE Groups.Id IN (SELECT GroupId FROM Group_Members WHERE User_Id = @userid)
```

Or this

```
SELECT * FROM Groups
INNER JOIN Group_Members ON Groups.Id = Group_Members.GroupId
WHERE Group_Members = @userid
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I am trying it now

Answer (score 2):

You will have to perform what is called a `JOIN`, it depends on what type you want, see [here](http://www.sql-tutorial.net/SQL-JOIN.asp).

So you can do something like the following

```
SELECT A.GROUP_NAME
, B.GROUP_DESCRIPTION

FROM TABLE1 A
JOIN TABLE2 B
ON A.UNIQUE_KEY = B.UNIQUE_KEY

WHERE GROUP_MEMBERS.USER_ID = $_SESSION['USER_ID']
```